# Загрузка файлов в браузер с помощью Win32

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32gui

Мне нужно загрузить файлы в браузер, чтобы отправить форму. Это действие необходимо периодически выполнять для данных в моем рабочем реестре.

Из-за информационной безопасности компании я не могу использовать Selenium.

Используя win32, я дошёл до того, что скачивание файлов необходимо. Когда я открываю папку, я не понимаю, как получить над ней контроль? Как передать свой путь? Как выбрать нужные файлы? А как нажать кнопку отправить?

Мне удалось обойти эту проблему только с помощью Shell.SendKeys.

Однако этот метод не является надежным. Мне кажется, что ошибка может возникнуть в любой момент.

```
# Copy path to clipboard
addToClipBoard(claim_path)

# Get focus on folder
activate_window(dialog_title)
time.sleep(2)

# Walk to enter file path, TABx5
for _ in range(5):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    shell.SendKeys('{TAB}')
time.sleep(0.5)
shell.SendKeys('{ENTER}')
time.sleep(0.5)

# Paste the path to the file folder, Ctrl+v and ENTER
shell.SendKeys(r'^(v)')
time.sleep(0.5)
shell.SendKeys('{ENTER}')

# Walk to select files, TABx4
for _ in range(4):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    shell.SendKeys('{TAB}')
time.sleep(1)

# Select all files, Ctrl+a
shell.SendKeys('^(a)') 
time.sleep(1)

# ENTER
shell.SendKeys('{ENTER}')
```

Comment: вы вот только представьте, что заходите на какой-нибудь сайт, и загруженный жабаскрипт незаметно для вас ваши файлы куда-то отправляет. это ж дыра дырищ, которой с огромной радостью воспользуются нехорошие люди. и вот вы спрашиваете, как бы сделать ровно то же самое. что вам можно на это ответить? разве что «удачи в поиске дыр в браузерах».

Comment: А в сторону "import requests" не смотрели? Создать сессия с сайтом и отправить в форму файл.

Comment: @Amgarak, достаточно проблематично делать через requests, так как сайт работает только в режиме Internet Explorer, динамически изменяет iframe и изменяет параметры. При этом не очень хорошо знаю requests, делал только простые-средние запросы, но видимо все же придется воспользоваться им.